# In Terraria, how do I see items that I can make but don't have all the materials for?

Tags: terraria

In my Terraria game on Xbox, if I have obtained all of the materials to make something but don't have it right now, it will show the ingredients to make the item.
How do I see what I need to make something on PC?

Comment: Tab out to a web browser :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing in the PC version.

If you want to see the possible crafting recipes you can give an ingredient to the **Guide** [image: guide] and he will show you the possible recipes and the required crafting station.

[image: screenshot]

Or, as [OrangeDog said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295710/in-terraria-pc-how-do-i-see-items-that-i-can-make-but-dont-have-all-the-materia#comment417893_295710), you can visit the wiki to see all the possible recipes: https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Terraria_Wiki

Comment: does he really show you the crafting station needed? can you supply a screenshot?

Comment: I'd like to say that it's preferable to use the official wiki, Gamepedia, rather than the fandom one on Wikia. This is as the Fandom wiki can be unreliable and outdated.

Comment: Back in 2015, on the forums, someone suggested a recipe book.  It was shot down because "the Guide already serves that purpose".  I can only conclude that 99% of players are complete and utter morons.  Because the Guide, as OP says, tells you what you can do with s.th., it doesn't (nothing _in-game_ does) tell you what you need for something.  I HATE games that rely on wikis with a FIERY PASSION.